# Scroll not display at right in TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-scrollview

I have a Textview in xml in which I define Scrollbar,
I also set padding and Background in TextView, But problem is that scrollbar is not displaying at right side, if we have paddingRight = 20dp then scroll display 20dp left from right edge.

for other controls like listview it always display at right

[image]

need solution for setting padding and scroll display at right side

**Edited:**

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/main_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dialog_lay"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dialog"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/dialog"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:maxLines="100"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:text="@string/dialog_text"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the XML please?

Comment: Where is the scroll view. Did you added?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `android:paddingRight = 2sp`?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Will keep that in mind for future reference @TheHippo. Thanx for the heads up.

Comment: Setting the padding should move the scroll view inside the text view, so setting `paddingRight` to a smaller value should move the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a scroll view in the LinearLayout?

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
     <ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        </TextView>
     </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

That should definitely include the scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below line

```
android:paddingRight="10dp"
```

or set to `android:paddingRight="0dp"`

then your scrollbar will be aligned to right.

**Padding is the space inside the border, between the border and the actual view's content.** So its obvious that if you give paddingRight in textview it will give padding also to scrollbar which is part of textbox.

Comment: but I want text padding from right and also scroll should display at right side, Is any other solution ?

Comment: No I don't think so as scrollbar is part of your textbox itself.